# Homebrew Permissions mess

Tags: ruby, permissions, homebrew

I installed Homebrew from my admin account. If I run `brew doctor` from that account I get no errors, but if I run `brew doctor` from my non-admin user account, I get warnings about several directories (`usr/local` and its subdirectories) not being writable, and suggestions that I `chown` them.

More recently, I installed RVM from my non-admin account (to ensure it was usable to that user and installed in their home directory). I then ran `rvm install 1.9.3` (again, as non-admin) and got an error warning me that `usr/local/bin` isn't writable and is required for Homebrew. Running `rvm requirements` yields the same warning.

Am I supposed to install RVM as non-admin, switch to admin when I install ruby version *with* RVM, and then be able to use RVM (for everything other than installing) from the non-admin account? Or is something else wrong here?

The RVM output when I attempted to install 1.9.3 follows:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p448.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
ERROR: '/usr/local/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

It's been suggested to me that I shouldn't have installed Homebrew while logged in as an admin, so I should uninstall (as admin), then reinstall as a regular user. I tried this, but when I run the install script as a regular user, the first thing it tells me is:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
This script requires the user myuser to be an Administrator. If this
sucks for you then you can install Homebrew in your home directory or however
you please; please refer to our homepage. If you still want to use this script
set your user to be an Administrator in System Preferences or `su' to a
non-root user with Administrator privileges.
```

I imagine this is why I installed it as an admin in the first place. Any help clarifying this?

Comment: Was there a reason you didn't follow the installation instructions on the Homebrew home page? If not, using your admin account uninstall (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ), then install as per Homebrew homepage.  Post the permissions for /usr/local.

Comment: @7stud I used my admin account to install Homebrew because I thought it made sense to do it that way. Does the Homebrew page specify what type of account should be used to install it? I wasn't able to find that. I'll try what you suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 74):

I had the same problem, I had to read the doc and think a lot.

```
$ rvm autolibs read-only # read more here: https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs
$ rvm install ruby  # or any version you want
```

This tells rvm to install ruby with current installed libs... default is read-fail which terminate rvm for missed requirements.

To use openssl (gem needs it, I had to rebuild ruby). Ask the computer admin install openssl with brew

```
$ brew install openssl  # if you want to install all dependencies run 'rvm requirements'
$ rvm reinstall ruby
or 
$ rvm install ruby
```