# ERROR: '/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it! Requirements installation failed with status: 1

Tags: ruby

I want to update my ruby 2.0 into 2.1 so I did this:

```
rvm install ruby-2.1.0
```

Then I received this error:

```
ERROR: '/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

The whole output is this:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx. /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
ERROR: '/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863211/homebrew-permissions-mess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix homebrew permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when trying to install ruby-2.7.5. I found [this blog post/article](https://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/89-fix-homebrew-error-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable-on-os-x-el-capitan).

Essentially, in newer versions of OSX, the `usr/local/bin` and `usr/local/share` directories are protected from being written to. You will need perform these steps:

1. Run `` sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/bin ``
2. Enter your password (required when running "sudo" commands)
3. Run `` sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/share ``
4. Then run your install commands.

Hope this helps!